# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \ln \left( 1+\dfrac{x}{n} \right)$, with $x>-1$ is pointwise convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Title says it all, really. I have to show, that:
 $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \ln \left( 1+\dfrac{x}{n} \right)$, with $x>-1$
is pointwise convergent, but I have no idea where to start. I am thinking, that I have to show it by comparison, but I am lost on what to compare it with.

Anyone got any ideas?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: When $x>0$ $$0<\ln\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right) < \frac{x}{n}$$ for all positive $n$, and when $-1\le x<0$ $$0>\ln\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right) > \frac{x}{n-1} $$ for $n>1$.

Comment: This proves nothing when $x<0$.

Comment: @Did True, I hadn't thought about it enough, thanks.

Comment: @Did Got it right?

Comment: Now it works. +1.

Answer (score 0):

By partial summation $$\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)}{n}=H_{N}\log\left(1+\frac{x}{N}\right)+x\int_{1}^{N}H_{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }\frac{1}{t\left(t+x\right)}dt
 $$ and taking $N\rightarrow\infty
 $ $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)}{n}=x\int_{1}^{\infty}H_{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }\frac{1}{t\left(t+x\right)}dt=x\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(t\right)}{t\left(t+x\right)}dt+O\left(x\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t\left(t+x\right)}dt\right)
 $$ and the integrals converges if $x>-1
 $.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use:
$$ \forall t>-1,\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+t)}=\frac{\gamma+\psi(t+1)}{t}\tag{1}$$
from the properties of the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), then it follows that your function is well-defined for any $x>-1$, since:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right) = \int_{0}^{x}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{dt}{n(n+t)}.\tag{2}$$

Answer (score -2):

$1+x \leq e^x$ $\forall x \in R$ so $(1+x/n)^{1/n} \leq e^{x/n^2}$ hence $1/n \ln (1 + x/n) \leq x/n^2$.